# Opening Intellicad via Excel

Tags: excel, vba, object

I have two separate Excel workbooks that open Intellicad and draw an object. I have declared my variable

```
  Dim icadApp As Object
```

followed by my statement to open Intellicad.

```
  Set icadApp = GetObject(, "icad.application")
```

This works perfectly on one workbook but not the other.

The other workbook, when run, results in a Run-Time Error 429 error : ActiveX component can't create object. It will work if I open Intellicad first and then run my Sub Routine.

All I have done is gone through my code on each of the workbooks and confirmed they are identical.

I also went to Tools > References to ensure Intellicad Object Library was selected and it was.

Comment: Re _I also went to Tools > References to ensure Intellicad Object Library was selected and it was._ since you are setting a reference to the library,  you could/should use early bound code (assuming Intellicad supports that)

Answer (score 1):

- `GetObject` raise error 429 if there isn't a Intellicad instance.
- ***Note:*** The parameters used in `GetObject` and `CreateObject` are not same.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim icadApp As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set icadApp = GetObject(, "icad.application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If icadApp Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set icadApp = CreateObject("icad.application")
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
    If icadApp Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Can't get the object of icad", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    Else
        icadApp.Visible = True
        MsgBox "App icad is ready"
        ' your code
    End If
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [CreateObject function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/createobject-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1010851)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [GetObject function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getobject-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1010959)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: Still doesn't work. 
Option Explicit
Sub SendCMDToiCAD(cmd As String)
Dim icadApp As Object
On Error Resume Next
Set icadApp = GetObject(, "icad.application")
On Error GoTo 0
If icadApp Is Nothing Then
On Error Resume Next
        Set icadApp = CreateObject("icad.application")
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
    If icadApp Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Can't get the object of icad", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
Dim icadDoc As Object
Set icadApp = GetObject(, "icad.Application")
Set icadDoc = icadApp.activedocument

icadDoc.sendcommand cmd & vbCrLf

End Sub

Comment: `Set icadApp = GetObject(, "icad.Application") Set icadDoc = ...` Why there is a duplicated GetObject? Would you mind to test the code w/o change? btw, please edit your post to share your code instead of using comments. It's too difficult to read and debug.

Comment: I copied your code exactly as is and it is still not working. It doesn't appear to do anything although there are no debug errors.

Comment: Please try the updated code. If `App icad is ready` pops up, it means `icadApp` is ready to use. The next code line should be `Set icadDoc = icadApp.activedocument`.

Comment: I have copied your code (above). It comes up with App icad is ready so I then added the code line Set icadDoc = icadApp.activedocument on the next line. icad still does not open.

Comment: I don't have CAD software, so I can't test the code. If the app is created by `CreateObject`, it is invisible by default. Use `icadApp.Visible = True` to show it up. The next step is to open your doc with the app. I guess it is `icadApp.LoadShapeFile`. `icadApp.activedocument` should work after that.